# LIKE %% not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I was trying to make a search in laravel but in laravel when I used

```
User::where('first_name', 'LIKE %', $name);
```

It Didn't work.
This is my user model.

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable {

use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'bio',
    'pic',
    'location',
    'password',
    'is_e'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function project() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}

}
```

I also tried not using like but then it was working properly. But not working at all with like. please help
thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to append `%` with value not with `LIKE` string. Try following code:

```
User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', $name."%"); // add % with $name
```

For match string from both side

```
User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%".$name."%");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', $name."%")->get();
```